# git push heroku master yields 'nothing changed' but doesnt recognize local changes?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am working on a website (django) that I uploaded online with heroku. Everything worked fine until I had to make a change in my views.py. 
Now when I do:

```
- git add .
- git commit -m "smtg"
- git push heroku master
```

It tells me that nothing change but I made some changes, it seems like it cannot see those. 
When I try git init it tells me "

> Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/Loic/Documents/my_site2/.git/

" 
Could you please help me it is a school project. 
Thank you

**EDIT:** now after git push heroku master I have :

```
 To https://git.heroku.com/cleanpharmacycle.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/cleanpharmacycle.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Did `git commit` succeed? What does `git status` after `git add .` say?

Comment: I got that response " On branch add-migrations nothing to commit, working tree clean"

Comment: I wonder how did you make a commit in the first place if there was nothing added to the staging area. You have to have something to commit.

Comment: Yes for sure but I have changed some lines of my codes. That is why I don't understand why "there is nothing to commit".

Comment: Have you created new files? Are the files you modified ignored?

Comment: Not at all, I just made some changes in my views.py and in an HTML page

Answer (score 0):

Check your current branch is master.

```
 git branch
```

If the pointer is not pointing the master, then check out to master branch

```
git checkout master
```

`git push heroku yourlocalbranch:master` if you want to push your local, non master branch to heroku master

Commit your changes and try to push to heroku

```
git commit -am "xxxyyzzz"    
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Really sorry but I begin with git. How do I know what to put in place of "yourlocalbranch"

Comment: You can find that out by typing `git branch` this would show you current working branch

Comment: Does it give any output? Also, if you've deleted contents from `views.py` then using `git add .` will not recognize that. You may consider using `git add --all` this would take effect of all changes that are made.

Comment: No, it did not, I now get the error I uploaded (see EDIT part of the post) ... but still thank you for sharing ideas

Comment: `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart.` This means your upstream branch is ahead of the local so simply try `git pull herkou master` to merge the latest changes and then try the push commands again.